# How to calculate minimax value with simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory, simplex

For the LP problems with only inequality constraints, I know how to use simplex method to give an optimal solution.

However, when I want to calculate the minimax value, how should I use the simplex method? For example, in the following LP problem,

\begin{align}
&\max & v \\
&s.t. & 5x_1 + 3x_2 \geq v \\
&     & 2x_1 + 6x_2 \geq v \\
&     & 4x_1 + 5x_2 \geq v \\
&     & x_1 + x_2 = 1 \\
&     & x_1, x_2 \geq 0
\end{align}

How should we build up an initial tableau for this problem?

Comment: Either replace $x_2$ with $1-x_1$ everywhere, or write $x_1+x_2\geq 1$ and $-x_1-x_2\geq 1$ instead of the equality.

Comment: Thanks! I could solve it with graphical method. I don't how to establish an initial tableau for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I see how to establish an initial tableau for LP problems with >= or = constraints. The following 2 videos are really helpful!

[How to Solve a Linear Programming Problem Using the Big M Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7MM8IbReMY&t=48s)

[How to Solve a Linear Programming Problem Using the Two Phase Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFWL3d6x5lA&t=58s)

Take the LP problem in my question and Big M method for example. We need first convert it to standard form, which is given as follow:

\begin{align}
&\max & v = x_3 - Ma \\
&s.t. & -5x_1 - 3x_2 + x_3 + s_1 = 0\\
&     & -2x_1 - 6x_2 + x_3 + s_2 = 0\\
&     & -4x_1 - 5x_2 + x_3 + s_3 = 0\\
&     & x_1 + x_2 + a = 1 \\
&     & x_1, x_2, s_1, s_2, s_3, a \geq 0
\end{align}

where $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are slack variables and $a$ is the artificial variable.

Rewriting $v=x_3-Ma$ as $v-x_3+Ma=0$, we can establish the following initial tableau:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Basis    & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & a  & RHS \\ \hline
s_1      & -5  & -3  & 1   & 1   & 0   & 0   & -1 & 0   \\ \hline
s_2      & -2  & -6  & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
s_3      & -4  & -5  & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
a        & 1   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1  & 1   \\ \hline
\tilde{v}& 0   & 0   & -1  & 0   & 0   & 0   & M  & 0   \\ \hline
v        & -M  & -M  & -1  & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0  & -M  \\ \hline
\end{array}

Note that, the $\tilde{v}$ row is temporary and not a part as the initial tableau, as it needs to be pivoted (the coefficient of $a$ is not $0$).

Then, we can see from the above tableau, the entering variable can be $x_1$, and the departing variable can be $a$. After pivoting, we get the following tableau,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Basis    & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & a  & RHS \\ \hline
s_1      & 0   & 2   & 1   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 5  & 5   \\ \hline
s_2      & 0   & -4  & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 2  & 2   \\ \hline
s_3      & 0   & -1  & 1   & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0  & 4   \\ \hline
x_1      & 1   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1  & 1   \\ \hline
v        & 0   & 0   & -1  & 0   & 0   & 0   & M  & 0  \\ \hline
\end{array}

The next entering variable is $x_3$ and the departing variable is $s_2$. After another pivoting, we get the following tableau,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Basis    & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & a  & RHS \\ \hline
s_1      & 0   & 6   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 3  & 3   \\ \hline
x_3      & 0   & -4  & 1   & 0   & 1   & 0   & 2  & 2   \\ \hline
s_3      & 0   & 3   & 0   & 0   & -1  & 1   & -2 & 2   \\ \hline
x_1      & 1   & 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1  & 1   \\ \hline
v        & 0   & -4  & 0   & 0   & 1   & 0   & M+2& 2   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Now, the entering variable is $x_2$ and the deparing varible is $s_1$. Thus, we can get the next-step tableau,

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Basis &x_1&x_2&x_3& s_1       & s_2 & s_3 & a         & RHS \\ \hline
x_2   & 0 &1  &0  &\frac{1}{6}& 0   & 0   &\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \hline
x_3   & 0 & 0 & 1 &\frac{2}{3}& 1   & 0   & 4     & 4   \\ \hline
s_3   & 0 & 0 & 0 &-\frac{1}{2}& -1 & 1   &-\frac{5}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \hline
x_1   & 1 & 0 & 0 &-\frac{1}{6}& 0 & 0  &\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \hline
v     & 0 & 0 & 0 &\frac{2}{3}& 1   & 0   & M+2 & 4  \\ \hline
\end{array}

As all the coefficients in $v$ row are positive now and **$a$ is not in the basis**, we get the optimal solution for the original LP problem. That is,

$$x_1=\frac{1}{2}, x_2=\frac{1}{2}, v=4.$$

Answer (score 0):

As 5xum has said, just replace $x_2$ by $1-x_1$

$\texttt{max} \  v$

$2x_1+3\geq v$

$-4x_1+6\geq v$

$-x_1+5\geq v$

Now you put the numbers on the RHS and $v$ on the LHS.

$\texttt{max} \  v$

$2x_1-v\geq -3$

$-4x_1-v\geq -6$

$-x_1-v\geq -5$

We can handle $v$ as an ordinary variable, $v\geq 0$

Multiplying the inequalities by (-1). The inequality signs of the constraints are turning around.

$\texttt{max} \  v$

$-2x_1+v\leq 3$

$4x_1+v\leq 6$

$x_1+v\leq 5$

$x_1,v\geq 0$

Therefore the initial table is

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&v&s_1&s_2&s_3&\textrm{RHS} \\ \hline 0&-1&0&0& 0&0 \\ \hline -2&\color{red}1&1&0&0& 3\\ \hline 4&1&0&1&0&6 \\ \hline  1&1&0&0&1&5  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

The first line is the objective function. According to the simplex algorithm the red marked element is the pivot element. Hint: The optimal solution is $(x_1^*,v^*)=(0.5,4)\Rightarrow x_2=0.5$

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, we could replace x_2 with (1-x_1) in this specific LP problem. However, it isn't a general method to deal with LP problems containing >2 decision variables.

Comment: @ShawnGuo The problem is not that there a two, maybe three, variables .  That is trivial.. The difficulty  is that the right hand side is variable. I´ve posted a way to obtain a standard form.

Comment: @ShawnGuo Btw, could you go on and finish the calculation?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll finish them later.

Comment: @ShawnGuo I´m looking forward to hear wether you could finish it or not.

Comment: I just finished my meeting. My answer has been updated now.

Comment: @ShawnGuo Nice. I read/check it later.

Comment: Thank you. If there is any mistake, please let me know.

Comment: @ShawnGuo It looks fine.But with the simplex method it is easier and much less time consuming. A comparison of the dimensions of our tables indicates that.